# JSharp Runtime 2.0 could not be installed

Tags: j#

I was trying to install an application and while installing it getting below error message:

```
JSharp Runtime 2.0 could not be installed. Please use windows update to manually install this update on your system.
```

To resolve this, I have already tried repairing the program but that did not work.
Apart from repair I have also downloaded the fresh program of it and that did not work too.
Can anyone suggest some ideas to install this J sharp correctly.